# "could not convert string to float value." What have I done wrong with my code?

Tags: python, string, point

I'm very new to coding and I don't know how everything works in Python. I know this code isn't write but I need to know how to do these things.

```
    #Write a program that prompts the user to enter six points and use Cramer's rule to solve 2x2 linear equations.
    a, b, c, d, e, f = float(input("Enter a, b, c, d, e, f: "))

    if a*d-b*c==0:
        print("The equation has no solution.")
    else:
        x= ((e*d-b*f) / (a*d-b*c))
        y= ((a*f-e*c) / (a*d-b*c))
        print("X is: " , x , "and Y is: " , y)
```

Comment: I think you  need to convert x and y to a string in your print statement

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the whole string to a float instead of each separate number.  That is, you convert "1 3 5 2 3 6" to a float which doesn't work.  I think what you mean is:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = map(float, input("Enter a, b, c, d, e, f: ").split())
```

Using `.split()` means it will convert the string to a list of number strings.  `map(float, ...)` will return a list of each number string converted to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of collecting input is incorrect, and x and y need to be converted to strings when being printed.

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
d = float(input("Enter d: "))
e = float(input("Enter e: "))
f = float(input("Enter f: "))

if a*d-b*c==0:
    print("The equation has no solution.")
else:
    x= ((e*d-b*f) / (a*d-b*c))
    y= ((a*f-e*c) / (a*d-b*c))
    print("X is: " , str(x), "and Y is: ", str(y))
```